# "The bill, please" or just "Bill, please"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, definite-articles, zero-article

Which short way of asking for a bill is correct?

> - Bill, please!
> - The bill, please!

Comment: Generally, at a bar or restaurant, it would be "Check, please" or "May I have my/our check, please"

Comment: "May I have the bill, please?" should be used. *Check* sounds so 1970s. 1980s, like *pop*, or Elvis Presley. *Check* sounds like *walkman* rather than android, *tennis shoes* rather than *sneakers*, like Britney and Spice Girls rather than Taylor Swift, or like Montgomery Gentry rather than Miranda Lambert.

Comment: Today I learned that Elvis Presley and Britney Spears were both products of the 80s. Thank you, @BlessedGeek.

Answer (score 6):

I think, if you're talking to a human being, you might like to take just a little more time. "Could we have our bill, please?" seems more in order to my British sensibility. Less in the way of being an abrupt order to a servant, perhaps?

Comment: It seems more in order to my US sensibilities also.  (Although in US, would say "check".)  It takes a fraction of a second to be polite.

Comment: @Margana, thanks a lot for your answer. And I definitely agree with you. However, I was interested in a difference between two phrases mentioned above.